# broadcast receiver for sms not firing

Tags: sms, broadcast

I've been through every post I could find and I still can't get my receiver to react to anything. My XML:

```
 <receiver android:name=".CollageSMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It's a large XML so at the top I have:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

and my Java:

```
public class CollageSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("sms","fired up");
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    String sender = "";
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    // get sender from first PDU
    sender = currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        text.append(currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
    }
    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

}
```

}

Thanks for any assistance you can render.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - here's what fixed it. I'm using Samsung note 4 which comes preset with a Samsung messaging app. I downloaded the Google messaging app and disabled the samsung messaging app and it now works like a charm.